# How to show image preview with bad resolution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, preview

I can show large images async like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    CGFloat scale = 1.f;
    UIImage *sourceImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    CGSize imageSize = (CGSize){self.size.width / scale, self.size.height / scale};

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
    [self drawInRect:(CGRect) {.size = imageSize}];
    UIImage *preloadedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    imageView.image = preloadedImage;
    });
});
```

But I should use some placeholder or activity indicator until image loaded.

Is there a way to show low resolution preview of image until image loaded async?

Comment: Where do you get imageData from?

Comment: It's local image, just big. I put images on scroll, and scroling is too slow and "choppy" (especially on Retina screens) if I don't prerender images. But when I prerender images in background, I should show prewiew (It's the best option)